# Ruby XMPP4R useer JID

Tags: ruby, xmpp4r

I use `xmpp4r` gem for create simple jabber bot. 
how do you know `jid` users in the room?
How do I know what `jid` posted a message?

Example code:

```
  @room.join Jabber::JID.new("#{conf}/#{nick}")

  @room.add_message_callback do |msg|
    #msg.jid? 
  end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The message object is inherited from the XMPP Stanza object. So the message should have a `msg.to` and `msg.from`, since it a group chat. The msg.to would be the JID of your group chat and msg.from would be the JID of the person who send the message.